# How to move a servo with a function

Tags: servo, code-review, code-optimization, functions

Im currently moving a servo from one side to another by using the typical for loop like this:

```
int lightON = 180;
int lightOFF = 90;

if (buttonState == HIGH) {

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  for (pos1 = lightOFF; pos1 <= lightON; pos1 += 1) {
    servo1.write(pos1);
    delay(15);
  }
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

}
```

That would be moving the servo one way and if I push the button again the servo would move another way.

```
if (buttonState == LOW) {

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  for (pos1 = lightON; pos1 >= lightOFF; pos1 -= 1) {
    servo1.write(pos1);
    delay(15);
  }
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

}
```

The thing is, I have this very same code in 3 other servos and I don't want to be repeating the same code with 2 different variables (pos and servo) over and over again, so I tried

```
void runServoLight(int pos, int light1, int light2, Servo servo, int state) { 

  if (state == 1) {

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);

  for (pos = light1; pos <= light2; pos += 1) {
     servo.write(pos);
     delay(15);
  }

  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

  } else if (state == 0) {

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);

  for (pos = light2; pos >= light1; pos -= 1) {
    servo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }

  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

  }

}
```

Now instead of running the whole for loop code I only run:

```
runServoLight(pos1, lightON, lightOFF, servo1, 1);
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to work and I can understand why, I may be writing the function wrong but im nor really sure. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: In your function, `light1` needs to be lower than `light2`. Looks like you got those mixed up in the call.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> ```cpp
> void runServoLight(
>         int pos, int light1, int light2, Servo servo, int state)
> ```

Here you are giving the list of parameters used by the function. In C++,
parameters are by default passed *by value*. This means that, when the
function is called, the arguments passed in the call are *copied* into
the parameters listed here, which are local variables of the function.
Changes to those parameters will not propagate to the arguments provided
by the caller.

This can be an issue for the `Servo` object. This object keeps some
internal state, which has the memory of the current configuration of the
timers. Since you are working on a copy of the provided object, the
original object is not updated when you act on the copy. I do not know
whether this is making your program misbehave, but it would be safer to
pass the `Servo` object *by reference*:

```cpp
void runServoLight(
        int pos, int light1, int light2, Servo &servo, int state)
```

This way the object will not be copied: the function will instead work
on the original object provided by the caller.

The same may apply to the *pos* parameter. The very first thing the
function does with this parameter is to overwrite it. Then there is no
point in receiving that value from the caller. You can instead remove
the parameter and create a local variable with the same name:

```cpp
void runServoLight(int light1, int light2, Servo &servo, int state) {
    int pos;  // local variable
    ...
}
```

If you want the caller's version of this variable to be updated, you
could pass it by reference, just like the `Servo` object. It is,
however, more efficient to keep the variable local and have the function
return the final position. The call would then look like:

```cpp
pos1 = runServoLight(lightON, lightOFF, servo1, 1);
```

One final point that is not visible in the snippets you showed: are you
doing *edge detection* on the buttons? Edge detection means that you act
on the *changes* of state of the buttons, not on the states themselves.
For example, you move from `lightOFF`  to `lightON` not when the button
state *is* `HIGH` but rather when it *turns* `HIGH`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, however, by rafactoring it makes your sketch more maintainable as duplicated code is removed:

```
void runServoLight(int pos, int light1, int light2, Servo servo, int state) 
{ 
  if (state == 1) {
    process(light1, light2, +1, servo);
  } 
  else if (state == 0) {
    process(light2, light1, -1, servo);
  }
}

def process(int this_light, int other_light, int delta, Servo servo)
{
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  for (pos = this_light; pos >= other_light; pos += delta) {
    servo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW); 
}
```

Instead of the state integer, it's more clear to use an enumeration and use a `switch` statement.

```
#include "Servo.h"

const int LED = 13;

enum EServoState { LEFT, RIGHT };

void runServoLight(int light1, int light2, Servo servo, EServoState state);

void setup() 
{
}

void loop() 
{
  int light1 = 1;
  int light2 = 2;
  EServoState state;
  Servo servo;
  runServoLight(light1, light2, servo, state);
}

void runServoLight(int light1, int light2, Servo servo, EServoState state) 
{ 
  switch (state)
  {
  case LEFT:
    process(light1, light2, +1, servo);
    break;
    
  case RIGHT:
    process(light2, light1, -1, servo);
    break;
  
  //default:
   // Handle program error
  }
}

void process(int this_light, int other_light, int delta, Servo servo)
{
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  for (int pos = this_light; pos >= other_light; pos += delta) 
  {
    servo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW); 
}
```